# Nokia display stopped working

Tags: arduino, spi, display, esp32

I had plenty of Nokia displays so I decided to use them with microcontrollers.

I found pinout instructions from [here](http://serdisplib.sourceforge.net/ser/pcd8544.html), connected one of the 3310 LCDs with my ESP32 because it runs on 3V3, and used [Adafruit PCD8544 library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-PCD8544-Nokia-5110-LCD-library) it worked fine for one minute but then stopped working.

Troubleshooting the connections didn't help and neither did reboots. Thinking the display might already be bad, I swapped the display with another one. Some flickering results later it also stopped working. I tried another one that looked similar but got no results at all.

All of the SPI pins had 1k resistors and the display was powered from the 3.3V pin of the ESP32.

I have other displays and different microcontrollers but before I do some accidental damage, what went wrong?

**Update:**

This display might be bad, the other two were connected the same way, with no short circuits (pins 5 and 6 need to be shorted) or lost connections.

I didn't connect the backlight as I could see the display fine for testing and planned on adding a separate backlight later.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: check the backlight circuit

Comment: We don't know how you built your circuit so we don't know what is wrong with it. Did you do any measurements of bad connections or incorrect voltages? If you built the regulator on a breadboard then all it takes is a single loose resistor to burn the display with overvoltage.

Comment: "display was powered from 3.3V pin of ESP32" @Justme